# Angular 8+ two way binding textarea in reactive forms

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to bind my textarea input.

HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <custom-element formControlName="firstName"</custom-element>

  <textarea formControlName="question" rows="6" placehoder"some text"></textarea>
</form>
```

TS:

```
formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
firstName: [{value: null, disabled: true}],
question:[null]
});

get firstNameControl(): AbstractControl {return this. formGroup.get('firstName');}
get questionControl(): AbstractControl {return this. formGroup.get('question');}

dosomething(): void {
 // fill firstname form api work fine
 // I can read the value with this.firstNameControl.value
}
```

Tried to bind textarea but no working solution yet.

```
message: string;

this.questionControl.valueChanges.subscribe(
      val => {
        this.message= val;
        console.log('questiontext' + this.message);
      }
    );
```

or

```
this.questionControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      debounceTime(500),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      tap(message => this.message = message),
      tap(data => console.log(data))
    ).subscribe();
```

if I add [(ngModel)]="message" to the textarea and remove formCotroleName it works.
But than you are combining two way of presenting the form which is not the way to go.

How can I two way bind a textarea or other form element with reactive forms?

Comment: I checked your code. Its working fine for me. I'm able to console log the values entered in textarea

Comment: which function did you use. the first one or second. when I debug it doesn't go into the function. when changing the input of the textarea.

Comment: I checked for first one. Just to clarify, you have subscribed to valueChanges in ngOnInit right?